# How to improve Django form errors?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

If I have a django form, where I want it to provide a bootstrap error         input (`<input type="text" id="inputError">`) to show an error instead of the bullet-list `{{ form.title.error }}`, how would I go about doing this? Right now I have:

```
  {% if UF.title.errors %}                   
        {{ UF.title }}
        {{ UF.title.errors.as_text }}
  {% else %}
        {{ UF.title }}
  {% endif %}
```

but instead of having UF.title in the first error, I would rather have UF.title but with the ERROR> how would I go about doing this?

Comment: a little bit unclear quetion cannot understand you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [django-bootstrap3](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3). 
It does exactly what you want.

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Display a form #}

<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Comment: Do i not put the form in models and forms.py then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Sure you create a `forms.py` and a form for your model. But in the template you use `{%bootstrap_from %} to render the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do for my code:

```
<div class="form-group {% if form.username.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
  {{ form.username }}
  {% if form.username.errors %}
  <span class="help-block">{{ form.username.errors.0 }}</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

And my `forms.py` looks like:

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=32, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```